# Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch 403 response when running a GET request in ASW S3 using chilkat

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chilkat

Getting this error when try to run a GET request on AWS s3. Detailed logs are attached below. Please help

26-Dec-2022 12:26:00 send error: List multipart uploads for key recovery/RÃ©cupÃ©ration_VOL-b001.spf
Unexpected response status code: 403

Error response:

```
Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
AWSAccessKeyId: AKIA4OGRTV42ZXNBHH47
StringToSign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20221226T065419Z
20221226/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request
34482fccab5255ab299ba1a1afe1429ab3b00d25920506f2b26eed3e695d0aaa
SignatureProvided: be3902f4cc91f6263ee88b6c2e90de2ad75858655aa6cb5205fb1950b149677f
StringToSignBytes: 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 32 31 32 32 36 54 30 36 35 34 31 39 5a 0a 32 30 32 32 31 32 32 36 2f 75 73 2d 65 61 73 74 2d 32 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 33 34 34 38 32 66 63 63 61 62 35 32 35 35 61 62 32 39 39 62 61 31 61 31 61 66 65 31 34 32 39 61 62 33 62 30 30 64 32 35 39 32 30 35 30 36 66 32 62 32 36 65 65 64 33 65 36 39 35 64 30 61 61 61
CanonicalRequest: GET
/
prefix=recovery%2FR%C3%83%C2%A9cup%C3%83%C2%A9ration_VOL-b001.spf&uploads=
host:recoverybucket333.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20221226T065419Z

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
CanonicalRequestBytes: 47 45 54 0a 2f 0a 70 72 65 66 69 78 3d 72 65 63 6f 76 65 72 79 25 32 46 52 25 43 33 25 38 33 25 43 32 25 41 39 63 75 70 25 43 33 25 38 33 25 43 32 25 41 39 72 61 74 69 6f 6e 5f 56 4f 4c 2d 62 30 30 31 2e 73 70 66 26 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 3d 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 72 65 63 6f 76 65 72 79 62 75 63 6b 65 74 33 33 33 2e 73 33 2e 75 73 2d 65 61 73 74 2d 32 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3a 65 33 62 30 63 34 34 32 39 38 66 63 31 63 31 34 39 61 66 62 66 34 63 38 39 39 36 66 62 39 32 34 32 37 61 65 34 31 65 34 36 34 39 62 39 33 34 63 61 34 39 35 39 39 31 62 37 38 35 32 62 38 35 35 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 3a 32 30 32 32 31 32 32 36 54 30 36 35 34 31 39 5a 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 0a 65 33 62 30 63 34 34 32 39 38 66 63 31 63 31 34 39 61 66 62 66 34 63 38 39 39 36 66 62 39 32 34 32 37 61 65 34 31 65 34 36 34 39 62 39 33 34 63 61 34 39 35 39 39 31 62 37 38 35 32 62 38 35 35
RequestId: 1SKCZB7ZCJJK4RMC
HostId: qQ/ElU917KLt7vm15qnfCvAZhb8NqL0GXyHt/dCcd6LOL76OhEz7C9bQ5i2zR2B0LO8xpHSvPYc+oe68V/usCA==

26-Dec-2022 12:26:00 Sending RÃ©cupÃ©ration_VOL-b001.spf
26-Dec-2022 12:26:19 send error: List multipart uploads for key recovery/RÃ©cupÃ©ration_VOL-b001.spf
Unexpected response status code: 403
```

I am trying to upload some files on S3 bucket and it is working for normal file names but not working when the file name contains some ASCII chars or accent marks. It failed with the above error shown in the description.